# LibreOffice Writer doesn't show footer in even pages when converting to html

Tags: html, footer, libreoffice

I have an HTML form that I'm trying to convert to PDF using LibreOffice. Also i have to use footer in my document. I create a document in html format with 5 pages but only odd numbers of page show footer. Even numbers don't show anything.

Actually, odd number pages have footer too but don't show . If i click mouse on footer part, it shows "+(plus)". When i click, it shows footer all even pages. I save the document and close it. Then open it again, but there is no footer in my even pages.

Hopefully, someone help me about this problem.

Comment: I think this is not a question for stackoverflow. Seems like offtopic. However, why don't you try with a programming language, like PHP ? It's easy, there are libraries that converts your html in pdf automagically

Answer (score 0):

Footers (headers, margins, etc.) in OpenOffice are defined in page styles.

Check if you are using different (alternating?) page styles.